# Slow query Optimization

Tags: sql, mariadb, query-optimization

Currently, Maria DB queries are getting slower and slower.

```
UPDATE `table1` 
SET `ANS` = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
             FROM `table2` 
             WHERE `uid` = 1011 AND `opt` = 1) 
WHERE `uid`= 1011;
```

The number of rows in `table2` is about 40 million. So this query seems to be slow.

How can I optimize it?

Comment: Have you used any indexes on table2? Please give details

Comment: I hope that the table1.ANS is not supposed to change everytime a table2 row gets added or removed. This is a one-time thing where you set an initial ANS value, yes? What I am talking about: Don't store data redundantly in a database. If you can always select the ANS value via `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 WHERE ui` = 1011 AND opt = 1`, then don't store it redundantly in the table1.ANS column.

Comment: Please edit your question to show (as text, not images) output of `select version()` and `show create table table1` and `show create table table2` and `explain UPDATE ...rest of your update`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You select the count of rows in table2 matching a particular uid and opt. Have an appropriate index for the lookup:

```
create index idx2 on table2 (uid, opt);
```

Then you access table1 rows macthing a particular uid. Have an appropriate index for this, too:

```
create index idx1 on table1 (uid);
```

Comment: Indexing would slow the performance on update of table1. Op needs to drop and recreate index each time whenever insert update would be needed on table1

Comment: @Himanshu: This is not true. In order to illustrate: Imagine tables with millions of rows and only one row in each table meating the uid/opt criteria. Do you really think that having to read the whole table2 in order to get the desired value and then reading the whole table1 only to find a single row to update would be faster than just reading one row in table2 via an index, then finding the one row in table1 via an index and than update it?

Comment: You din get what i meant. I am saying creating index for select and dropping for update on table 2. There, this would work perfect as desired. Manual dropping and recreating index on table2 (in this case) would be an additional effort but will work

Comment: @Himanshu: The only reason to drop an index (of table1) here, would be the case where table1 is huge and the update affects very many rows of it. We neither know how many rows are in table1 nor how many rows will get updated, though.

Comment: Yeah thats what i was about to say this could be the less frequent case. It appears as a static result which is rare. So, for 1 row result you are correct it wouldnt cause any problem but majority of cases it will

Comment: Currently, `uid` of table1 is the primary key, and `uid` and `opt` of table2 are indexed . Do I need the (`uid`, `opt`) pair index?

Comment: Yes, if you have two separate indexes, one on uid and one on opt, these are not as good as an index one the combination of (uid, opt). But that all depends on the data. How many rows do you get for one uid, how many for one opt and how many for an (uid, opt) pair? If the latter doesn't result in much less rows than both of the others, then the index on (uid, opt) won't bring much benefit.

Comment: In the case of pairing the two keys, much less data is retrieved. In this case, it might be effective. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Himanshu there is almost never a good reason to delete an occasionally used index in MySQL or mariadb; additional indexes don't slow down any update the way they do in postgres.

Comment: @ysth: You have misread this. The uid is primary key for table1, not for table2.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner you are correct, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. The below will be faster than your original update statement as in that update statement the count would be evaluated each time per each row. Hence, slower below the with clause ensures the result is queried once on the table itself. Then, can use it any number of times like below

```
With data1 as 
(
SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt
             FROM `table2` 
             WHERE `uid` = 1011 AND `opt` = 1) 
Update table1 t1 , (Select cnt from data1) t2
Set ans=t2.cnt
WHERE `uid`= 1011;
```

Comment: Please don't write code-only answers. Why should the OP try this? What does this update statement different from the original one? It does look a bit obfuscated, and I don't see any reason why this should be faster. You are using the wrong join type, by the way. I don't know whether MariaDB will issue a syntax error as it should, but this is not an `[INNER] JOIN`, but a `CROSS JOIN`. An inner join is invalid without an `ON` clause.

Comment: Edited & have removed the join with ascii join

Comment: Ah, okay, you think that the subquery in the original query will get executed once per table1 row. This is very unlikely and would shed a very bad light on MariaDB's optimizer. You don't have to fall back to an old comma-separated join like it was used in the 1980s either. Just use the proper standard-SQL `cross join`.

Comment: The thing is it would be from the table1 directly each time in the original query even though its a single row but would be slower than my query as here it would be using the with clause result everytime rather than calculating again from the table itself. You can try to run both the queries and if mine is slower i can delete my answer

Comment: In the original query, the subquery is non-correlated. This means it just selects one value regardless of the rows in table1. So the DBMS optimizer will first run the subquery, and the result may be 100. Then it will run the main statement which becomes a mere `UPDATE table1 SET ANS = 100 WHERE uid= 1011` then. Don't think the DBMS will run a loop, only because it looks like a loop to you. SQL is a 4GL declarative language. We tell the DBMS what to do, not how to do it. The DBMS will (hopefully) always find the best execution plan. In the given scenario this is even easy-peasy.

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this:

```
UPDATE `table1` c
LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT `uid`, COUNT(*) as cnt
     FROM `table2` 
     WHERE `uid` = 1011 AND `opt` = 1
     GROUP BY `uid`) AS b ON b.uid = c.uid
SET `ANS` = c.uid
WHERE c.uid = 1011
```

Or join trough ID: